# Is there a difference in appearance between Yubaba and Zeniba?

Tags: spirited-away

Is there a difference between Yubaba's and Zeniba's appearance in Spirited Away? A couple other sources say they're "nearly identical", not exactly, but fail to say why.

Comment: They seem identical to me... Maybe "they are nearly identical" means "they look the same, but have different personalities"? Hence, "nearly".

Answer (score 5):

[Zeniba](http://spiritedaway.wikia.com/wiki/Zeniba) and [Yubaba](http://spiritedaway.wikia.com/wiki/Yubaba):

[image: Zeniba][image: Yubaba]

Quoted from Zeniba's page:

> and is seen, on one occasion, wearing glasses to help herself create a handmade hairband for Chihiro, hinting that she may be farsighted.

And from Yubaba's page:

> Unlike her sister Yubaba is not shown with glasses in the film.

<sub>(It's been a long time since I've seen Spirited Away, so I don't know how much of her appearance in the movie that "on one occasion" covers.)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

One main difference I saw is that Yubaba wears a ruby pendant on her dress, since she loves money and jewels. Zeniba doesn't care much for wealth, so she doesn't wear one.